# Having troubles installing ChezScheme-9.5.2 in Codeanywhere

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, codeanywhere, chez-scheme

Trying to install ChezScheme-9.5.2.tar.gz on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Codeanywhere. During sudo make command, get error message failed because uuid/uuid.h is missing. How do I get uuid/uuid.h in a location where $ sudo make can find it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were additional missing files, so did the following:

```
$ sudo apt install uuid-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libx11-dev
```

The make still fails, but not because of missing files. I believe the 512MB ram is too small.

In order to answer your question "What was your error message?" I've attempted to duplicate what happened. Think I've done so and here is the error message:

```
compiling cpnanopass.ss with output to cpnanopass.a6le
Mf-base:487: recipe for target 'bootall' failed
make[4]: *** [bootall] Killed
Mf-base:164: recipe for target 'allx' failed
make[3]: *** [allx] Error 2
Mf-base:181: recipe for target 'bootstrap' failed
make[2]: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'build' failed
make[1]: *** [build] Error 2
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
cabox@Python_Lua:~/workspace/ChezScheme-9.5.2$
```

First, had to do '$ sudo apt-get install uuid-dev' because 'apt install' does something different than 'apt-get install', which got uuid.h installed.

Comment: After properly installing a missing file 'uuid.h' I duplicated the problem I characterized as 512MB ram possibly being too small to complete the installation of ChezScheme-9.5.2 from a tar.gz file. The answer to your question is shown in my edited remarks above.

Comment: I noticed today that my platform now has 1024MB ram. ChezScheme-9.5.2 was successfully installed from a tar.gz file.